# What is a good service that will allow me to practice options trading with a pretend-money account?

Tags: trading, options, financial-literacy, day-trading

I want to get a little more practice before I put my money on the line.

I was using Paper Money from thinkorswim through school, but my account is bugged where the buying power will not update. The only way to fix it is to reset the account, and because it is a school account, I don't have access to do that. I am graduating in a few days if that affects my eligibility for any of the free training programs.

I really don't need a ton of analysis tools, yahoo finance has most of what I need.

Please excuse me if this is the wrong place.

Comment: http://www.cboe.com/TradTool/
several to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Try wallstreetsurvivor.com

It gives you $100k of pretend money when you sign up, using which you can take various courses on the website. It will teach you how to buy/sell stocks and build your portfolio. I am not sure if they do have Options Trading specifically, but their course line up is great!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://sparkprofit.com/

You practice with real market prices, and it's free. Plus you can get real money pay outs if you do well. I earned 1 cent! hahaha I gave up trying to make money from it, but you get an idea of doing trades and how impossible it is to predict what the price will be.

It has some tutorials and helpful things too.

Comment: "I earned 1 cent" -- that's a lot more then some actual traders make!

Answer (score 0):

Try ThinkOrSwim by TDAmeritrade. It allows you to paper trade with a powerful trading platform. There's also a mobile app so you can trade on the go. Good luck!